# Using Timer and colour to display morse code

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Hi Guys i'm trying to let my Screen blink a morse code out using timer , but no luck, can you spot any problem?

Sry but i feel sad for those who cant think out of the box and just mark a -2 without even understanding the situation.

Anyway, found about using await Task.Delay(100) but gridHalfFront.Opacity = 1; isnt being "activated" when its being read. not sure why.

```
async public void RunMorseCode()
        {
            foreach (char c in word.ToCharArray())
            {
                string rslt = Codes[c.ToString()].Trim();
                foreach (char c2 in rslt.ToCharArray())
                {
                    if (c2 == '.')
                    {
                        gridHalfFront.Opacity = 0;
                       await Task.Delay(100);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        gridHalfFront.Opacity = 0;
                        await Task.Delay(1000);

                    }
                    gridHalfFront.Opacity = 1;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: You don't seem to output anything anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) and/or System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000) inside yr loop to make yr screen blink on and off

```
    gridHalfFront.Opacity = 1;
    if (c2 == '.')
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    else
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
    gridHalfFront.Opacity = 0;
```

change it to the way it best for you, but dont use those timers

Comment: does System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); even work with Metro app? I tried that just now, .Thread not found

Comment: Check this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/bb07ce11-ae4b-4f27-971c-15bb50191588

Comment: Hi , i found a solution , updated my question , my gridHalfFront.Opacity = 1; isnt updating, not sure why

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing the Timer event handler. After calling Start() and after the elapsed time a Tick event from the Timer will be raised. There you have to change the opacity.

Comment: void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {

            gridHalfFront.Opacity = 0;
         
        }
?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the use of a Timer. If you put the following code at the top of `StartTimer` you will see what I mean.

```
Console.WriteLine("Started {0}", inputTiming);
```

When you run you will get a bunch of timers are being created immediately. This is not what you want for two reasons. Firstly, they are all assigned to the same variable, so the second is 'logically' killing off the first, etc. Secondly, you don't want them created all at once, as all of the 1 second ones will all run at the same time after 1 second, and all of the 3 second ones will run together after 3 seconds. And, as already mentioned, to run code after the timer expires you need to hook up the event.

**BIG EDITS** Sorry didn't realise you were looking at Metro. What I have said above still holds, but I will back away from providing a solution.

Given the comments about `Sleep()` not working on Metro, I think you need to so all the code inside the timer for one character, and then set the interval for the next character from within the timer. Will provide some code in a few minutes...